# Как привязать прокручивание колеса мыши к определенному блоку на странице?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, прокрутка

На странице есть один div 100% высоты со скроллбаром. Больше на странице нет скроллбаров вообще и не предвидится. При наведении курсора на div и прокручивании колесика он скроллится, но вот если отвести курсор от него и прокрутить, скроллится, естественно, не будет. Как пофиксить, чтобы всегда скроллился именно этот div? Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: А остальные блоки должны быть видны на экране, когда происходит прокрутка?

Comment: в качестве идеи https://learn.javascript.ru/mousewheel

Comment: @edem, да. Они должны быть неподвижны.

Answer (score 1):

Задаём всем блокам, которые не должны прокручиваться и должны быть видны на экране:

```
position: fixed;
```

В таком случае прокручиваться будет вся страница, вместе с необходимым div, вне зависимости от расположения указателя мыши на странице, а вышеупомянутые блоки будут всегда отображаться на экране в момент прокрутки.

Comment: Тогда контент из этого div'a будет накладываться на контент из неподвижных div'ов выше и ниже. Другой бы вариант. Может быть с использованием javascript. Думаю, без него такую проблему не решить.

Comment: @Анатолий задайте ему необходимый `z-index`. P.S. JS тут — из пушки по воробьям.